# Kohana ORM - Table's type

Tags: kohana

In Kohana ORM, do we need to set up the database table with type of InnoDb. I learn that MyISam is a little bit faster than InnoDb. For example, [here](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/auth#mysql_schema)

is the Database schema for ORM driver, can we simply use MyISam without defining foreign-keys and leave the rest to our code using $_has_many, $_belong_to...?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana ORM doesn't differentiate between mysql table engines and it cannot use foreign key constraints to manage dependencies automatically.

So whichever table engine you use - you still has to specify `$_belongs_to` etc relation maps manually.

Comment: Thanks, so i should understand that it doesn't have to be InnoDb to use ORM, right? :D

Comment: @Le Trung Hieu: it can be of any engine